# Lines of nonsense code where wordpress pages should be: Avada

Tags: wordpress

A few of the pages on my organisation's website are displaying code - not real code - just nonsense code, like this:

```
���ْG�(�,��?���fUH쵲اDQj�������he    $�@B�.
```

Go to http://www.eavi.eu/about-us/ for an example or check the image here:

[image]

I have emailed Avada's support, but I was wondering if anyone has encountered anything similar in the past and might be able to help.

Comment: I think Its your editor problem at the time of save content in database

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: The content which you are displying are coming from database or static content

Answer (score 0):

I removed the Tiny MCE editor plugin and this fixed everything.

It seems there is an issue with the Avada theme and this plugin which I confirmed with someone else.